# Removing subarrays that share a key-value pair with another multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filtering, array-difference

I have 2 arrays as below. I want to remove data from `array2` if `array1` has the `stu_id`. final array should be like `result_array`.

```
$array1 = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [stu_id] => 1
            [name] => mr.a
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [stu_id] => 3
            [name] => mr.b
        )
)

$array2 = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [stu_id] => 1
            [data] => abc
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [stu_id] => 2
            [data] => xyz
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [stu_id] => 3
            [data] => aaa
        )
)

$result_array = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [stu_id] => 2
            [data] => xyz
        )
)
```

I tried array_diff, `$result_array = array_diff($array2, $array1);`  but it's not working.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: array_diff, array_column, array_filter - Read about the functions

Answer (score 3):

Temporarily assign keys using `array_column()` with `stud_id` (`NULL` retains the full subarray data), then use `array_diff_key()` to filter, and `array_values()` to reset the keys:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0217fec57eb951a2ccbc91c4e31c96f4c686391f))

```
$array1=[
    ['stu_id'=>1,'name'=>'mr.a'],
    ['stu_id'=>3,'name'=>'mr.b']
];

$array2=[
    ['id'=>1,'stu_id'=>1,'data'=>'abc'],
    ['id'=>2,'stu_id'=>2,'data'=>'xyz'],
    ['id'=>3,'stu_id'=>3,'data'=>'aaa']
];

//var_export(array_column($array1,NULL,'stu_id'));
//var_export(array_column($array2,NULL,'stu_id'));
var_export(array_values(array_diff_key(array_column($array2,NULL,'stu_id'),array_column($array1,NULL,'stu_id'))));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'stu_id' => 2,
    'data' => 'xyz',
  ),
)
```

---

If you'd like to use a foreach loop structure, generate a filtering array of `stu_id`'s from `$array1` and write a conditional check on each iteration of `$array2`.  This method doesn't not modify the original arrays, so they can be reused "down script".

Code:

```
$stu_ids=array_column($array1,'stu_id');
foreach($array2 as $row){
    if(!in_array($row['stu_id'],$stu_ids)){
        $result[]=$row;  // auto-index the qualifying subarrays
    }
}
var_export($result);
// same result as above method
```

Comment: @tenten does this answer satisfy or do I need to explain something further?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array1 as $data1){
    foreach($array2 as $k => $data2){
        if($data2["stu_id"] == $data1["stu_id"]){
            unset($array2[$k]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
$result_array = $array2;
```

Comment: You'll need to reset the keys in the result with `array_values()`.

Comment: Still preserving original `$array2` keys.  Just add `array_values ()` to `$result_array` declaration.